# terraform creating multiple databases in aurora

Tags: terraform, amazon-aurora

we have a terraform script to create a Aurora (postgresql) instance with one database. We can login to the terminal and create a new database in the same database instance identifier. Is there a way to do that in the terraform script directly?
could not find any thing on the internet and trying to duplicate the 
resource "aws_rds_cluster"  failed.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create the single instance cluster?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `postgresql` provider and define `postgresql_role` and `postgresql_database`.